# Transmission torrent client hangs up after upgrade

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, transmission

I had a 10.10 ubuntu installation and upgraded to most recent 11.04. After the upgrade when I start the transmission the window appears but no components inside and after a while it becomes grey and the option to force quite appears.

Comment: Offtopic: I find Deluge a lot better than Transmission

Comment: @Ashfame +1 for the suggestion I ll give it a try, i have tried azureus and the server version of μtorrent but wasn't really statisfied.

Comment: Offtopic? Please, try Deluge, qTorrent (lighter), Flush (lightest) and see that they not have such issues. I am obsessed with the idea that people stay with Transmission just because it's default and think there must be a reason why.

Comment: How can default software of Ubuntu be off-topic? I stay with transmission because I don't care I just need some downloads, and it is there so I don't have to research about it and install extra stuff etc.. I agree that probably there are better tools out there, like always. And its a year ago and there was a way to fix it. A puzzle is always a challenge ;) help make good things, better! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem solved by enabling [the test ppa of transmission](https://launchpad.net/~transmissionbt/+archive/ppa). It seemed to be transmission-gtk error.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:transmissionbt/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install transmission-common transmission-gtk
```

Comment: Where or how do you do that? Is that with synaptic ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try reinstalling the Transmission packages you have installed:

```
dpkg -l | grep "ii  transmission" | sed -e 's/ii  //g' -e 's/ .*$//g' | xargs sudo apt-get install --reinstall
```

**Command description:** `dpkg -l` lists all the installed packages and sends the output to `grep`, which searches the list for `transmission`. `sed` then parses that and removes the description, package version, etc. so only the package name is shown. `apt-get` then reinstalls those packages.